# how to delete in asp.net without from a static list(not from database)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new with asp.net. I'm trying to build a small project, where I have a static list of drivers and their details. I'm trying to delete but its not going to well. can someone please check my delete functions?

```
public ActionResult DeleteDriver(int id)
        {

            var driver = _drivers.Single(d => d.id == id);
            _drivers.Remove(driver);
            return View(driver);

        }

        // POST: Drivers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DeleteDriver(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            var driver = _drivers.Single(d => d.id == id);
            if (TryUpdateModel(driver))
            {
                //...
                return RedirectToAction("index");

            }
            return View(driver);
        }
```

Comment: What error do you get? And why you are returning View with the deleted item which doesn't exists anymore?

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban thanks now it is deleting for me. I didn't notice that I returned to  a view that doesn't exsist anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the driver from returned `View`. You can return to index page with a list of drivers or you can return an empty `View`.

```
var driver = _drivers.Single(d => d.id == id);
_drivers.Remove(driver);
return View();
```